# How can I speed up the rate at which my health recovers?

Tags: candy-box-2

Each encounter results in your health getting reduced as you take damage. Your health automatically regenerates outside of an encounter (ie: on the map or in the inventory) but this regenerates quite slow and doesn't appear to scale with increased health.

How can I speed up the rate at which my health recovers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know exactly what you mean; the pink gloves take too long to refill the health bar once you have more than 1,000 or so HP because it still refills at the same rate as when you have only a couple of hundred.

What you want is the [unicorn horn](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=unicorn_horn): “`Its powerful healing powers will help you a lot.`” and it really does; it fills up your health bar *much* faster. If you use it in conjunction with the pink gloves, then you can fill up nearly 2,000 HP in ~45 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to wear my pink gloves (which you can build in the well with chocolate). Then I go on an easy mission like desert, because in quest in regenerates really fast. So I just need to do it 2-3 times and I get full life.

Also in the water, you can get more life than damage and quit when you have all the life.

Or, the octopus king, when he is dead, the life still regenerating fast, so you can kill him (that is fast) and then wait.

**EDIT**: The Best place is when you have access to the castle and boots of introspection is to go to the bottom left room (the one with spikes) and wait there.

Comment: While my HP was still low, I found the Octopus king to be the best because unlike most other levels, this one does not end when you get to the right-hand side, so you can just leave it there for a while until you are full. However once you have a lot of health, kalina’s question becomes relevant: it takes a *long* time for it to fill up.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Boots of Introspection, combined with the Pink Gloves, and go onto the Troll's bridge, and just wait until I regen all my health.

Comment: This is the same as Jesus’ answer; the pink gloves regenerate too slowly when you have 1,500+ HP and want to actually play rather than just leave and come back later.

Answer (score 0):

Start a quest (Desert or Bridge)
Use health potion
Exit quest
Repeat till you're at full health